# Linker Error LNK2019 in Visual C++

Tags: c++

I have been encountering a linker error when attempting to call a class method from my main method. I have searched for an answer but nothing seems applicable to my issue, any help will be much appreciated.

### FileSystem.h

```
#ifndef FILE_SYSTEM_H
#define FILE_SYSTEM_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

#include "SortingAlgorithms.h"
#include "SortingAlgorithms.cpp"

using namespace std;

class FileSystem
{
private:
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    template <class T>
    void fillArrays( T randomArray[], T sortedArray[], T backwardArray[], int size );

public:
    FileSystem();
    ~FileSystem();

    bool openFile(string fileName);
    void writeToFile(string output);
    void createTestFiles(string testFiles[]);

    template <class T>
    void fillArrayFromFile(T list[], int size);
};

#endif
```

### fillArrayFromFile

```
template <class T>
void FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile(T list[], int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        inFile >> list[i];
    }

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.seekg(inFile.beg);
}
```

### pa2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#include "TimerSystem.h"
#include "FileSystem.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FileSystem file;
    int testArray[10];

    file.openFile("test-10-0.txt");
    file.fillArrayFromFile(testArray, 10);
}
```

### Error:

```
pa2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile<int>(int * const,int)" (??$fillArrayFromFile@H@FileSystem@@QAEXQAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
C:\Users\Matt\Google Drive\Programming\Data Structures & Algorithms\PA2-9-15-2012\Debug\PA2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Which source file is the implementation of `FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile()` in, exactly?

Comment: What file contains the definition of fillArrayFromFile?  This code has to be in a file that is part of the project so it gets compiled and linked along with pa2.obj, or it has to be in a .lib that is specified as a linker input.

Comment: I have the FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile() in FileSystem.cpp which includes FileSystem.h. The other methods within the source file work properly when called from the main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling code that calls a `template` function, the compiler must be able to see the full implementation of the function. At the point the compiler is building `pa2.cpp`, the compiler is only looking at `FileSystem.h` and the definitions within the header file (and other header files included from `pa2.cpp`, of course). It does not look at the contents of `FileSystem.cpp` at that point.

To fix this, move the implementation of `FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile()` to the *header* file instead of the `.cpp` file. You can do that one of two ways:

```
class FileSystem {
public:
    template <class T>
    void fillArrayFromFile(T list[], int size);
};

template <class T>
void FileSystem::fillArrayFromFile(T list[], int size)
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
class FileSystem {
public:
    template <class T>
    void fillArrayFromFile(T list[], int size)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```